# Kendo Grid - How can I pass and store the UID of a <tr> to a very distant function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with detail rows.

When a user clicks to open the details, we interrupt the detailInit to launch a kendo dialog, to ask a yes/no question.

If they answer yes, we want to open the detail row for them, but I'm losing track of what row they were clicking on - not sure how to keep the UID to pass it along to other functions - it's no longer in detailInit() so I'm not sure how to pass the UID to another, unrelated function so I can open the details with:

```
grid.expandRow(grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']"));
```

Is there a way, when someone clicks on the `$("a.k-icon k-plus")` to store that temporarily so I can call to it from a distant function, and then delete it once run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
var expandedUID;

function detailInit(e) {
    expandedUID = e.masterRow.data("uid");
}

function externalFunction(){
    grid.expandRow(grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + expandedUID + "']"));
}
```

Hope this helps someone!